# How can i get ResourceGroup costs in Azure?

Tags: powershell, command-line-interface, azure-cli

I want to get how much each resourcegroup costs using Az cli

I have tried

```
az consumption usage list --start-date 2023-01-01 --end-date 2022-01-28
```

but gives an error Subscription scope usage is not supported for current api version Please use api version after 2019-10-01
I have also tried

```
Get-AzConsumptionUsageDetail -ResourceGroup "rg1" -StartDate 2023-01-01 -EndDate 2022-01-28 |  Select-Object *
```

It says the module is not installed.

How can i get the costs ?

Answer (score 0):

I have reproduced in my environment and expected results as below and I followed [Microsoft-Document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/az.billing/get-azconsumptionusagedetail?view=azps-9.5.0):

```
Get-AzConsumptionUsageDetail -ResourceGroup "resource group name" -StartDate 2023-01-01 -EndDate 2023-03-28 |  Select-Object *
```

[image]

You can use the above command  in Cloud Shell of azure Portal.

Even in local it is working fine as below:

[image]

Comment: **Comments have been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/252867/discussion-on-answer-by-rithwikbojja-how-can-i-get-resourcegroup-costs-in-azure); please do not continue the discussion here.** Before posting a comment below this one, please review the [purposes of comments](/help/privileges/comment). Comments that do not request clarification or suggest improvements usually belong as an [answer](/help/how-to-answer), on [meta], or in [chat]. Comments continuing discussion may be removed.